# IOS Open GL ES 2.0 inverted(BGRA) texture on device but RGBA on simulator

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I create default "ios game" project on Xcode and try to bind texture. All works correct on Ipad Simulator, But when I connect real device the texture colors has inverted.

Here is OK for simulator:

```
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ww, hh, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

And here is OK for real ipad Device:

```
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ww, hh, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Besides diffuse color always works correct (as RGBA).

Here is shader:

```
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture; 

void main(){
  gl_FragColor = colorVarying * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
```

This is normal? Is it possible to somehow set the textures default format as rgba? Would not that one device(for example Iphone 6) will display rgba colors, and the other(for example Ipad Air) bgra?

Comment: Make sure your image loading code does not have any dependencies on the endianness of the machine. Freeimage for example has such issues.

Comment: how are you loading the texture data and how are you setting `colorVarying`?